# How to jump to the next line in python if my list of strings is getting too long?

Tags: python

Line 1.

```
names_boys = ["john", "paul", "peter", "roger", "pete", "johnson", "derick", "christof", "andrew"]
```

#if this list is quite long and I want to continue on the next line (line 2), instead of having a very long line of code, what do I do?

I have tried using "\n" but nothing.

bear with me. I am new to python

Comment: You mean you want a multi-line list?

Comment: do the enter after a comma

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simple:

```py
names_boys = ["john", "paul", "peter", "roger", "pete",
              "johnson", "derick", "christof", "andrew"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either go down a line or use the `\` at the desired location like so:

```
names_boys = ["john", "paul", "peter", "roger", "pete",\
              "johnson", "derick", "christof", "andrew"]
```

keep in mind that you can't have any white space or comments after the `\`

Comment: There is no need for `\\` here

Comment: gave a few options :) it's true like you wrote that the easiest way is to just take it down a line.

Answer (score 0):

> Python statements are usually written in a single line. The newline character marks the end of the statement. If the statement is very long, we can explicitly divide into multiple lines with the line continuation character (\).

> Python supports multi-line continuation inside parentheses ( ), brackets [ ], and braces { }. The brackets are used by List and the braces are used by dictionary objects. We can use parentheses for expressions, tuples, and strings.

by second rule, you can split you line as

```py
names_boys = [
    "john", "paul", "peter", "roger", 
    "pete", "johnson", "derick", "christof", 
    "andrew"]
```